# Sort an NSArray of NSDictionary

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have an NSArray of NSDictionary unsortedArray look like:

```
  ( 
    {symbol = "ABC"; price = "9.01";}
    {symbol = "XYZ"; price = "3.45";}
    ...
  (
```

Here is the sorting code:

```
  NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"price" ascending:YES];
  NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor];
  NSArray *sortArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortedDescriptors];

  NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"symbol" ascending:YES];
  NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor];
  NSArray *sortArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortedDescriptors];
```

The sorting results for symbol key is ok but for price key is not sorted.  What could be wrong?  The price is in NSString but want to sort it look like

```
  3.45
  9.01
  ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This does not seem to be your actual code: You use the variable name `sortedDescriptors`, which in not defined in the code above. Please post you actual code.

Comment: "What could be wrong?" Well, what *did* go wrong? The two prices are sorted properly, after all.

Answer (score 2):

use NSNumber for the price in the dictionary and the sort descriptor will work on the numerical value rather than as a string, e.g.

```
NSArray *dictArray = @[ @{@"symbol" : @"ABC", @"price" : @9.01},
                        @{@"symbol" : @"XYZ", @"price" : @3.45} ];
```

or, if the price is a string

```
NSArray *dictArray = @[ @{@"symbol" : @"ABC", @"price" : @"9.01"},
                        @{@"symbol" : @"XYZ", @"price" : @"3.45"} ];
```

use a comparator which requires comparing the price of a pair of dictionaries, e.g.

```
    NSArray *sortedArray = [dictArray
                        sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *dict1,
                                                                       NSDictionary *dict2) {

    double price1 = [[dict1 valueForKey:@"price"] doubleValue];
    double price2 = [[dict2 valueForKey:@"price"] doubleValue];

    if(price1 > price2)
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;

    if(price1 < price2)
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;

    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;

}];
```

Comment: thanks.  But the unsortedArray is already existed.  I need to sort this array.

Comment: I've changed my answer to include a sort using a comparator to sort correctly numbers held as strings